# Escaping single quotes in shell for postgresql

Tags: linux, postgresql, shell, escaping, psql

I'm trying to execute SQK through psql under postgres account. I'm able run SQL
that doesn't contain quotes

```
root@server:/home/rosta/SCRIPTS# su postgres -c "psql -c 'SELECT NOW()'"
              now
-------------------------------
2014-06-07 09:38:17.120368+02
(1 row)
```

The problem appears with an SQL query that contains quotes like SELECT 'hi'. I'm testing with simple 'hi', but I would like to execute something like this from a shell script.

```
su postgres -c "psql -c 'create database $DB_NAME template=template0 encoding='utf8' owner=aaa lc_collate='cs_CZ.utf8''"
```

Can anyone advise me how to escape quotes around encoding and collate in the command above

Some of my tests:

```
root@server:/home/rosta/SCRIPTS# su postgres -c "psql -c 'SELECT \'hi\''"
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
root@server:/home/rosta/SCRIPTS# su postgres -c "psql -c 'SELECT \\'hi\\''"
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
root@server:/home/rosta/SCRIPTS# su postgres -c 'psql -c \'SELECT \\'hi\\'\''
```

Comment: You can play around with `leaning toothpick syndrome` Why don't you just stay in the root account?  Root is allowed to run psql.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I usually do is use double quotes (`"`) for `postgres -c`'s argument and escaped double quotes (`\"`) for `psql -c`'s argument. That way, I can use single quotes (`'`) inside the SQL string with no problem:

```
[root@mycomputer ~]# su postgres -c "psql -c \"SELECT 'hi'  \" "
 ?column? 
----------
 hi
(1 row)
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Could the downvoter please explain his reason?

Comment: In short, this is from a security perspective extremely dangerous -- it enables not only SQL injection, but also shell injection if someone tries to insert a variable this way without knowing its contents. That is to say, I'm going to assume that to make this useful in the real world it would be `SELECT '${greeting}'`, but if `greeting=$(rm -rf ~)` or its more-nefarious sibling `greeting=$'\'$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)'`, then the `postgresql` account's home directory is at risk.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way is to use a 'here document' , which ignores all quoting:

```
#!/bin/sh
DB_NAME=my_data_base

psql -U postgres postgres <<STOP_IT
create database $DB_NAME template=template0
  encoding='utf8'
  owner=aaa
  lc_collate='cs_CZ.utf8'
  ;
STOP_IT
```