# Heroku and PostgreSQL command-line using -c/--command to process query with characters that need to be escaped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, command-line, escaping, heroku-postgres

I am familiar with the syntax of MySQL as far as escaping characters is concerned.  However, as the Ruby on Rails application that I am currently building uses PostgreSQL I am struggling to get the command line to behave properly.  I am trying to run a basic query through a shell script when rebasing the database to a more recent backup of the live database.

For example the command that I am trying to run looks like the following:

```
psql db_name u_name -c "UPDATE users SET encrypted_password = 'crazy_long_hash_here';"
```

I understand the security implications of the query being run, but this is for a development workstation where we need to be able to log in as varying classes of users to test different functionality.

The problem that I get when running this command is that the application the crashes with a Ruby Exception:

```
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash
```

This message clearly states that the value of the hash is no longer correct.  However, if I run the same command in the standard command line style as follows:

```
psql db_name u_name

db_name=# UPDATE users SET encrypted_password = 'crazy_long_hash_here';
UPDATE (row count)
```

the command resets the password to the desired universal password and I am able to log in as any user to properly test any functionality.

What part of the escaping procedure am I missing? The following characters outside of the standard [0-9][a-zA-Z] character set are used in the hash:

```
$ .
```

Any help would be appreciated, as google seems strangely silent on the matter.  The only other question I have found is not helpful: [Escaping single quotes in shell for postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095203/escaping-single-quotes-in-shell-for-postgresql)

---

**UPDATE**

I have also tried this with the here-document syntax to no avail:

```
psql db_name u_name << EOF
  UPDATE users SET encrypted_password = 'crazy_long_hash_here';
EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as the case would have it, A little more fiddling resulted in the answer.  When running the command though the standard `psql` interface, I needed to escape the `$` to `\$`.

However, this continued to fail when running:

```
heroku pg:psql -c "UPDATE users SET encrypted_password = 'hash_with_\$_in_string';"
```

The answer to this was to **double escape**  the characters, meaning:

```
heroku pg:psql -c "UPDATE users SET encrypted_password = 'hash_with_\\\$_in_string';"
```

Once both the `\` and the `$` are each escaped, the heroku toolbelt properly interpreted the hash and all is well.

Comment: This is nothing to do with `psql`. `$` is a shell metacharacter for interpolation of variables into `"double quoted"` strings. This is why it's important not to show redacted/trimmed info in posts unless you *really* have to, because you just create confusion and waste time. You also didn't mention you were running `psql` via Heroku's wrapper script; not important as it turns out, but it really could've been. BTW, the reason a here document didn't work is that you have to disable metacharacter interpolation with `psql ... <<'EOF'`. Note single quotes around end marker.

Comment: @CraigRinger - Thank you for the comment.  As you can tell, this is not an area where I am an expert, but I greatly appreciate your expertise.  Thank you for the comment, as I believe it will help others.  I realize that I left out the `heroku psql`, but as the case would have it, I didn't believe it to be important either.  I really did try to be as explicit as I could.  Thank you for the critique, and I will try to improve my questions as much as I can in the future.