# How to format quotes in a PostgreSQL query from a bash script

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql, kubernetes, psql

I am trying to query a kubernetes Postgres pod using a bash script where i want to allow user to enter a variable and then use that variable to query. My bash script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "give a last name"


read t

kubectl exec -it postgres-pod -- bash -c "psql -U postgres -c 'Select * from users WHERE last_name=\"$t\"'"
```

I have tried all combinations of single and double quotes but i am unable to pass a string type username. Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Is there an error message? If so, add it to your question (no comment).

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: @JamesBrown Sorry for the typo  I either get a "column last_name doesn't exist" or "There is a syntax error at the end of line"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escaping single quotes in shell for postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095203/escaping-single-quotes-in-shell-for-postgresql)

Comment: `bash -c "psql -U postgres -c \"Select * from users WHERE last_name='$t';\""`

Comment: @JamesBrown It works!! thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The simple, but bad, solution is

```sh
bash -c "psql -U postgres -c \"Select * from users WHERE last_name='$t'\""
```

This gets the quoting right, but is vulnerable to SQL injection. What if the variable `t` contains a value with a single quote?

Dealing with that is not so simple; the only way I could think of is using `psql` variables like this:

```sh
echo "Select * from users WHERE last_name = :'var'" | bash -c "psql -U postgres -v var=\"$t\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need bash, should this work ?

```
kubectl exec -it postgres-pod -- psql -U postgres -c "SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_name='$t';"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i already tried this and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

i solved it using @James Brown's answer above:

```
bash -c "psql -U postgres -c \"Select * from users WHERE last_name='$t';\""
```